# How do I remove the smallest and largest element in an array in a manner that's appropriate to C++?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have an array of ints and I want to call a function to remove the smallest and largest values. By remove I mean that if my initial array was 7 elements in length, the new array has 5 elements. The order of the remaining elements does not matter. I've come up with some ways to do it, but I'm not sure which one is the C++ "way" of doing it, if that makes sense.

What I have now is that I use std::sort to sort my array and then I use a for loop to copy the results starting from the second element and stopping at the second-to last element into a new array with the appropriate size. How should I return the array though?

I can't return the newly created array because it's a local variable to the function. I could pass the new array as an argument to the function, but isn't that more of an older, C-style way of doing this? I could also use std::vector, but then I'd have to wrap the array in a vector and then unwrap it (the numbers need to remain in an array of ints). Seems like overkill, doesn't it?

I'm coming from a Python background and I just want to know what's the more appropriate way to do this in C++.

Comment: Since you already wrote some source code, you could add it to your question so we could start from there and point you to the right direction.

Comment: Why are you sorting if you just need to remove max and min?

Comment: @Moron: I am curious as to what your more efficient method of finding max and min is. :)

Comment: @Zan: You can do the min and max finding with no more than 3n/2 compares. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424800/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-the-minimum-or-maximum-value-from-an-array-of-numbers/1183989#1183989

Comment: min_element and max_element in the standard library return iterators to the respective values.

Comment: @Moron: Then after you have the min/max values you have to copy the array, doing 2n compares (min or max for each i). With the sorted array you just copy with no compares. Would have to do math to see how that works out.

Comment: @Zan: While finding the max and min you can do the copying over, so you can do it in one pass. Sorting will use Omega(nlogn) compares on average and you cannot modify sorting to do the copy while you sort.

Comment: @Moron: How can you possibly copy while finding min and max? Element a[x] may be min or max but you cannot know that until you reach a[n].

Comment: @Zan: You can! if you keep track of both max and min at the same time. Consider first 4 elements, you found max and min. You copy the other two. Now you look at next 2 elements (i.e. the 5th and 6th). Compare with current max and min. You now have 4 elements and 2 of them are max and min. You copy over the other two. Continue. In one pass you have copied over the elements which are not max or min.

Comment: @Moron: I was curious how this worked so I implemented it. You can see it in my answer here if interested.

Comment: @Zan: I know, you already have my upvote :-)

Answer (score 8):

If the numbers had to remain in an array of ints and the order didn't matter, I would do it this way:

```
void MoveHiLoToEnd(int orig[], int size)
{
    int* last = orig + size - 1;
    int* maxp = std::max_element(orig, orig + size);
    std::iter_swap(maxp, last);
    int* minp = std::min_element(orig, orig + size - 1);
    std::iter_swap(minp, last - 1);

    //now the original array contains max and min elements moved.
    //to the end. You can ignore them or copy elements except
    //those last two to a new array, if really necessary.
}
```

The signature

```
int* MoveHiLoToEnd(int* begin, int* end);
```

is more in C++ library style <strike>and it could be changed to a template</strike>

```
template<typename ForwardIter>
ForwardIter RemoveHiLo(ForwardIter begin, ForwardIter end);
```

returning the iterator to the old min element (past the new truncated collection), but I doubt it's worth it. That would require different (less convenient I think) parameters in the call.

**EDIT**

Sorry template idea is bad. Things get complicated. You would have to require bidirectional iterator (which makes the template less universal than it could be with forward ones. for min and max_element forward is enough)

```
template<typename BidirectionalIterator>
BidirectionalIterator RemoveHiLo(BidirectionalIterator begin, BidirectionalIterator end);
```

or nonstandard input parameters, because you need iterator to the last element.

Comment: This seems like the most "c++" solution to me without using vector anyway

Comment: Since C++11 we can get close to double the throughput for large arrays (ones that don't fit in cache all at once) by using `std::minmax_element` instead of `max_element` and `min_element` separately.

Answer (score 7):

Forget about arrays and use `std::vector<int>` instead.

```
using std::vector;

vector<int> WithoutHiLo(vector<int> orig)
{
     std::sort(orig.begin(), orig.end());
     vector<int> newVec = vector(orig.size());
     std:copy(&orig[1], &orig[orig.size()-1], &newVec[0]);
     return newVec;
}
```

UPDATE (per comment):

```
vector<int> WithoutHiLo(vector<int> orig)
{
     std::sort(orig.begin(), orig.end());
     return vector(&orig[1], &orig[orig.size()-1]);
}
```

If you really need an array for input:

```
vector<int> WithoutHiLo(int orig[], int size)
{
     std::sort(&orig[0], &orig[size]);
     vector<int> newVec = vector(size);
     std:copy(&orig[1], &orig[size-1], &newVec[0]);
     return newVec;
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you use the vector begin/end iterator constructor to build it instead of using std::copy? Seems that would be better.

Comment: @Zan: Good point (I've been doing too much C# lately, and forget these things...)

Comment: One other nitpicky thing I just noticed. Should throw a std::out_of_range or similar if size < 2. :)

Comment: @Zan: Yes, but some things should be left as an exercise for the student.. ;-)

Comment: Why sort? That's unnecessarily inefficient when a linear search will do.

Comment: -1. "Forget about arrays" You know, all the benefits of std::vector aren't free - there is overhead and extra memory involved. And you don't need to sort. And you could modify vector in place without another one (swap minimum/maximum with last two values, then resize the vector with size() - 2). And you return vector by value, which may involve copy constructor. Bad advice, IMO, no matter how you look at it...

Comment: @SigTerm: I agree with everything but the last part. NRVO eliminates that overhead.

Comment: @SigTerm: You're wrong. std::vector isn't free- but there's std::array for the stack. No decent compiler will invoke the copy constructor here. While it's true that the function could perhaps be optimized further, fundamentally it's a far, far better function than taking an int orig[].

Answer (score 4):

There are two operations you need to perform: find the min and max, and then remove the min and max. By recognizing these steps and remember the single-responsibility principle, you maintain clean code.

The first operation is *missing* in C++03. As it stands, without making your own function the only way is to go through the range *twice*, one with `min_element` and `max_element`. This is algorithmically unnecessary.

C++0x recognizes this defect and adds `minmax_element` (and `minmax`). If you have a compiler that supports C++0x, just use `std::minmax_element` defined in `<algorithm>`. If not, [use Boost's](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/boost/algorithm/minmax_element.hpp) or steal Boost's/write your own.

We can now complete the first operation:

```
int array[] = {4, 7, 6, 5, 9, 4, 3, 1, 11};

// see footnote for begin and end
std::pair<int*, int*> mm = minmax_element(begin(array), end(array));
```

With pointers (or iterators) to the elements, we now remove them. With a statically-sized array, the typically solution is to move them to the end, ala:

```
// and take care your array has enough elements!
std::swap(*mm.first, end(array) - 2);
std::swap(*mm.second, end(array) - 1);
```

Then you just treat the array two elements shorter; this is O(1). Another solution, which maintains order, is to copy/shift all the elements down by one; this is O(N).

And that's it. You can wrap the above into some form of `erase_minmax` function.

<sub>*`begin` and `end` just make things a bit easier, they are:</sub>

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
T* begin(T (&pArray)[N])
{
    return pArray;
}

template <typename T, size_t N>
T* end(T (&pArray)[N])
{
    return pArray + N;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more of STL type of way.

```
std::vector<int> vec; 
//populate your vector
vec.erase (max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end()) );
vec.erase (min_element(vec.begin(), vec.end()) );
```

But complexity is linear, so maybe not the best if faster removal is required.

Comment: Kind of inefficient though. Or at least not as good as it could be.

Comment: @Zan, that is why I have mentioned the rider. And I would really love to know how it is inefficient compared to what i.e. not the copying around done by the vector and time complexity ? :)

Comment: Because it scans the array twice and memmoves twice.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting isn't necessary. And what if the int array has either a duplicate min or max? Chopping off the first and last value after a sort won't solve the problem.

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

void
rm_minmax(int* x, int sz, std::vector<int>& v) {
    int min = x[0];
    int max = x[0];
    int Sz = sz;

    while (sz) {
        int dv = x[sz-1];
        if (dv < min) min = dv;
        if (dv > max) max = dv;
        sz--;
    }

    for (int i=0; i < Sz; i++) {
        if (x[i] != min && x[i] != max) v.push_back(x[i]);
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int foo[] = { 5, 1, 33, 22, 54, 1, 44, 54 };
    int sz = sizeof(foo)/sizeof(int);
    std::vector<int> x;
    rm_minmax(foo, sz, x);
    sz = x.size();
    for (int i=0; i < sz; i++) printf("%d\n", x[i]);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I got into solving this and the discussion with Moron in the question comments above spawned the following. The code is heavily modified but is [based on this answer by Rayhan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424800/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-the-minimum-or-maximum-value-from-an-array-of-numbers/1183989#1183989).

Compile it and call it with an input file of numbers like `./a.out < /tmp/numbers` or pipe it some numbers like `echo 1 5 2 10 -2 0 | ./a.out`

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

template<class T, class U>
U copy_without_min_max(T in_begin, T in_end, U out)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type value_type;
    // min and max hold the min and max values found so far in the loop.
    value_type min, max;
    // small and big hold the values from the current pair being evaluated.
    value_type small, big;

    typename std::iterator_traits<T>::difference_type len = std::distance(in_begin, in_end);
    // in_stop is either the end of input or one less if length is odd.
    // This is needed so that in_begin will equal in_stop while advancing 2 at a time.
    T in_stop(in_end);
    T in_next(in_begin);
    ++in_next;
    // evaluate the first pair to find initial min,max values.
    if ( *in_begin < *in_next ){
        min = *in_begin;
        max = *in_next;
    } else {
        min = *in_next;
        max = *in_begin;
    }
    if ( len % 2 != 0 ) { // if len is odd
        --in_stop;
    }
    std::advance(in_begin, 2);

    // Advance two elements at a time tracking min and max as we go.
    // Whenever a previous min or max is evicted, output it to the destination.
    // Whenever a min or max is confirmed, output the element to the destination.
    while( in_begin != in_stop ) {
        in_next = in_begin;
        ++in_next;
        if ( *in_begin < *in_next ) { // one comparison
            small = *in_begin;
            big = *in_next;
        } else {
            small = *in_next;
            big = *in_begin;
        }
        if ( min > small ) { // one comparison
            *out++ = min;
            min = small;
        } else {
            *out++ = small;
        }
        if ( max < big ) { // one comparison
            *out++ = max;
            max = big;
        } else {
            *out++ = big;
        }
        std::advance(in_begin, 2);
    }
    // Special case for odd number of elements.
    // Output either the last element or min or max, depending.
    if ( in_begin != in_end ) {
        if ( *in_begin > min && *in_begin < max ) {
            *out++ = *in_begin++;
        } else if ( *in_begin < min ) {
            *out++ = min;
        } else if( *in_begin > max ) {
            *out++ = max;
        }
    }
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> in;
    std::copy(
        std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),
        std::istream_iterator<int>(),
        std::back_inserter(in)
    );
    copy_without_min_max(
        in.begin(),
        in.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " ")
    );
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For some reason, I'm really finding it hard to follow your algorithm. Would you mind commenting what each of the variables is used for?

Comment: @Paul: Added comments for you.

Answer (score 0):

Using the STL vector to wrap your array of ints really doesn't make sense, as you said, and because you need to retain the array data structure, you might just as well not venture outside of that data structure.

Edit: Removed my non-answer from before and added sample code.

I've added some code below to demonstrate a way that doesn't involve the STL vector, but you're more than welcome to pursue that.

```
//Other stuff here...
int test[] = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
JunkFunc(test);
//whatever else your program needs to do afterward...

void CFlirPumpDlg::JunkFunc(int *arr)
{
int junkArr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    //The above array is just dummy data; removing the high/low would go here
memcpy(arr, &junkArr, sizeof(junkArr));
}
```

Comment: Why would you use an array over a vector?

Comment: How are pointers "the" way to do things in C++? I can do a lot of stuff without touching a pointer.

Comment: C has no references; C++ has those.

Comment: He didn't want to use a vector since he had a requirement of maintaining the array of ints.  That's why you'd use that.

Comment: You've got me on the references.  I misspoke.

Comment: Of course you can do things without pointers, but they are very powerful and very useful.  I haven't touched a piece of C++ in years (since High School computer science) that doesn't use pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your question denotes a lack of understanding of C++ array semantics - you can't 'remove' elements from C++ arrays(since they are raw memory). You can reallocate the memory to a smaller area; you can use a `vector`; you can copy to a smaller array.

But you can't do foo.delete_first() where foo is an array.

Here is my solution. It gives you a new array (allocated in the heap) with the characteristics you desire. It will handle duplicate maxes/mins. My solution has more lines of code than a STL solution and I would recommend using the STL if possible.

```
//Returns a new'd array of type T.
//Delete when done.
// Big-O = O(std::sort(len)) + len + O(cost-of-new)
template<typename T>
T* filter(T* t, int len)
{
  T* trimmed;
  std::sort(t[0], t[len-1]); //consider that this will not compile if T is not comparable

  //Here you could use a predicate approach, but let's write it out...
  int num_mins = 1; //t[0] is always min
  int num_maxes = 1; //t[len-1] is always max
  for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
  { 
     if(t[i] == t[0])
       num_mins++;
     if(t[i] == t[len-1]) 
       num_maxes++;
  }

  trimmed = new T[len - (num_mins + num_maxes)];
  return trimmed
}
```

Comment: The OP seemed to prefer arrays. Also, I wasn't sure what the standard libraries did in the case of duplicates.