# How to find maximum value in any range of an array in log(n) time?

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search-tree, indexed

E.g. Array: {1, 5, 2, 3, 2, 10}

Range: 0-1 Answer: 5
Range: 2-4 Answer: 3
Range: 0-5 Answer: 10
etc.

Comment: You can't. In order to find the maximum in an unsorted sequence, you will have to look at each value at least once. That makes the algorithm O(n).

Comment: @sbi: Unless you preprocess the array and build a search tree/table/whatever to give the maximum of any subrange more quickly than searching the subrange. Presumably, that's what the question is asking about, although it's a bit terse.

Comment: @Mike: While that is true, I wouldn't call such a beast an "unsorted sequence". I did leave this loophole intentionally, you know? `:)`

Comment: have you considered building a quantum computer to do that?

Comment: you can take a look at my comment.

Comment: http://wcipeg.com/wiki/Range_minimum_query gives several algorithms. The optimal is linear preprocessing time plus constant query time.

Answer (score 11):

If the array is not sorted, then there is no way to do what you're asking for.

To find the maximum you at least need to *inspect* all elements in the range, which takes O(*n*).

If you allow some form of preprocessing of the data, it's easy. You could just build an n<sup>2</sup> lookup table with the answers. Then you could find the maximum for any range in constant time.

Comment: Yes, this is called "range maximum query"

Answer (score 4):

This is impossible.  You'd have to visit every element.

If your array is sorted a-priori, then it's O(1) operation.

Answer (score 1):

See also here:
[What is the best way to get the minimum or maximum value from an Array of numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424800/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-the-minimum-or-maximum-value-from-an-array-of-number)

As the others pointed out it's impossible

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel Talamas if i understood you correctly, you wanted this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int maxlement(int range1,int range2) {
std::vector<int> v{ 1, 5, 2, 3, 2, 10 };
std::vector<int>::iterator result;

result = std::max_element(v.begin()+range1, v.begin()+range2+1);
int dist = std::distance(v.begin(), result);
return v[dist];

}
int main() {
int range1,range2;
cout<<"From ";
cin>>range1;
cout<<"To ";
cin>>range2;
cout<<"Max Element Is "<<maxlement(range1,range2);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Only in logarithmic, not linear, time.