# find min max in an array of integer, performance issue

Tags: java, algorithm, performance

I wrote these two methods here to find min and max. #2 is based on this answer from this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13544576/259562).

```
private static Pair classicMinMax(int[] elements) {
    int min = MAX_VALUE;
    int max = MIN_VALUE;

    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        int e = elements[i];
        if (e < min) min = e;
        if (e > max) max = e;
    }
    return new Pair(min, max);

}

private static Pair divideAndConquer(int[] elements) {
    int min = MAX_VALUE;
    int max = MIN_VALUE;

    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length - 1; i += 2) {
        int a = elements[i];
        int b = elements[i + 1];

        if (a > b) {
            if (b < min) min = b;
            if (a > max) max = a;
        } else {
            if (a < min) min = a;
            if (b > max) max = b;
        }
    }

    if (elements.length % 2 != 0) {
        int lastElement = elements[elements.length - 1];
        if (lastElement < min) min = lastElement;
        if (lastElement > max) max = lastElement;
    }
    return new Pair(min, max);
}
```

If I run simple benchmarks like this:

```
@Test
public void timingsBoth() throws Exception {

    int size = 1000;

    for (int i = 1000; i < 10_000; i += 1000) {
        int arraySize = size * i;
        System.out.println("step is " + arraySize);

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(arraySize);
        int[] elements = new int[arraySize];
        for (int k = 0; k < arraySize; k++) {
            list.add(k);
        }

        Collections.shuffle(list);
        Integer[] integers = list.toArray(new Integer[0]);
        for (int k = 0; k < arraySize; k++) {
            elements[k] = integers[k];
        }

        long start = currentTimeMillis();
        classicMinMax(elements);
        long stop = currentTimeMillis();
        long result = stop - start;
        System.out.println("classic is " + result);

        start = currentTimeMillis();
        divideAndConquer(elements);
        stop = currentTimeMillis();
        result = stop - start;
        System.out.println("divideAndConquer is " + result);
    }
}
```

}

And I'm usually getting this result:

`step is 1000000
classic is 8
divideAndConquer is 11
step is 2000000
classic is 2
divideAndConquer is 5
step is 3000000
classic is 11
divideAndConquer is 17
step is 4000000
classic is 5
divideAndConquer is 10
step is 5000000
classic is 4
divideAndConquer is 16
step is 6000000
classic is 6
divideAndConquer is 14
step is 7000000
classic is 6
divideAndConquer is 18
step is 8000000
classic is 8
divideAndConquer is 20
step is 9000000
classic is 8
divideAndConquer is 24`

Did I get the algorithm wrong? I was expecting at least a similar result.

Comment: @YCF_L probably a static import of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` etc

Comment: @dierre This is *not* how benchmarking is done.

Comment: At least related: [*How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Comment: @YCF_L since these arrays contain integers you can't have an integer bigger than `MAX_VALUE` or smaller than `MIN_VALUE` so the OP is correct.

Comment: Use `nanoTime()` at least for benchmark // and try method separtly OR ttry with other order for algorithm / and the array you give to the second algo is already sorted ^^

Comment: @alfasin it was the first thing I thought, I started reading about JMH. Do you suggest anything else?

Comment: Yes, I would run the methods separately, each one in a loop that runs it at least 100K times, and calculate an average of these runs. Also, the GC requires a "warmup" stage.

Comment: @alfasin I added an answer with my findings. I hope you can give me feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, following advices from the comments I think I did a better benchmark.
What I used is [Java Microbenchmark Harness](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/). I never used it before so I based my test on this handy [tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-performance/jmh.html#getting-started-with-jmh).

What I did was creating a JMH test like follows:

```
public class MinMaxBenchmark {

    @State(Scope.Benchmark)
    public static class MyState {

        int arraySize = 50_0000;
        int[] elements = new int[arraySize];

        @Setup(Level.Trial)
        public void doSetup() {
            List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(arraySize);
            for (int k = 0; k < arraySize; k++) {
                list.add(k);
            }
            Collections.sort(list);
            Integer[] integers = list.toArray(new Integer[0]);
            for (int k = 0; k < arraySize; k++) {
                elements[k] = integers[k];
            }

        }
    }


    @Benchmark @BenchmarkMode(Mode.SampleTime   ) @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    public Pair classic(MyState state) {
        return classicMinMax(state.elements);
    }
    @Benchmark @BenchmarkMode(Mode.SampleTime) @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    public Pair divide(MyState state) {
        return divideAndConquer(state.elements);
    }

}
```

I put special attention to create the array (input data) outside the benchmark creating a `@State` with a `@Setup` method for initialization. Than I wrote the to `@Benchmark` methos. I was really careful in returning the result so *dead code* could be avoided (it's all in the tutorial).

With this setup I run several trials. This one is the last attempt:

`Benchmark                                  Mode      Cnt  Score    Error  Units
MinMaxBenchmark.classic                  sample   994028  0.202 ±  0.001  ms/op
MinMaxBenchmark.classic:classic·p0.00    sample           0.153           ms/op
MinMaxBenchmark.classic:classic·p0.50    sample           0.180           ms/op
MinMaxBenchmark.classic:classic·p0.90    sample           0.259           ms/op
MinMaxBenchmark.classic:classic·p0.95    sample           0.311           ms/op
MinMaxBenchmark.classic:classic·p0.99    sample           0.409           ms/op
MinMaxBenchmark.classic:classic·p0.999   sample           0.567           ms/op
MinMaxBenchmark.classic:classic·p0.9999  sample           0.942           ms/op
MinMaxBenchmark.classic:classic·p1.00    sample           2.617           ms/op
MinMaxBenchmark.divide                   sample  1226029  0.164 ±  0.001  ms/op
MinMaxBenchmark.divide:divide·p0.00      sample           0.126           ms/op
MinMaxBenchmark.divide:divide·p0.50      sample           0.149           ms/op
MinMaxBenchmark.divide:divide·p0.90      sample           0.201           ms/op
MinMaxBenchmark.divide:divide·p0.95      sample           0.230           ms/op
MinMaxBenchmark.divide:divide·p0.99      sample           0.327           ms/op
MinMaxBenchmark.divide:divide·p0.999     sample           0.522           ms/op
MinMaxBenchmark.divide:divide·p0.9999    sample           0.945           ms/op
MinMaxBenchmark.divide:divide·p1.00      sample           3.199           ms/op`

Where actually the *divide* is only losing on **p1.00** (I need to find the meaning).

So I guess it was a problem of the way I handled benchmarking.

Thank you for the help in the comments, especially @alfasin.

Comment: `divide is only losing on p1.00 (I need to find the meaning)` more complicated code for no gain due to perfect branch prediction.

Comment: If this an attempt to answer the question, can you a conclusion section at the start or end (e.g. "as you can see, these values are much closer to the expected ..., so this was indeed just a benchmarking issue and the algorithm was working fine" or whatever makes sense)? If this is not an attempt to answer, it would probably be better suited as an edit to your question.