# How can we find out that the number is maximum or minimum entered by user without using sorting?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

{Like user entered 1,2,32,12,55,5,61,23 and from which we have to find out maximum or minimum number without using any sorting technique.
}

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: I didn't use any sort technique and the answer is `61`

Comment: Amit you don't need to sort to find max and min in the array. All you need is simple comparisons. Try creating a program if you get issues in the program then post the question.

Comment: Java or C, which one?

Comment: @UUIIUI it's just asking for an algorithm, so the language doesn't really matter *and* it doesn't belong here -> shouldn't receive *any* answers IMHO

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is homework without any attempt

Comment: so I edited the question & modified the tags.

Comment: Using C and simple comparisions will make it lengthy

Comment: @AmitKumar have you heard of loops?

Answer (score 4):

Iterate across the numbers set, keeping track of the current highest and current lowest numbers, comparing each number in the set to these, and reassigning the highest or lowest when appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You can read each input and compare that to the current value of some variable "maximum".  If the input is higher than the current value make that input the new maximum value.  You can do the same for minimum.

If you get the input all in one line, you'll have to parse it.

Comment: But i dont wanna write a lot of a code its just an example if user enters 10000 numbers can be compare them all

Comment: @AmitKumar: You have no other choice. You have to examine __every__ element to find the maximum/minimum. There is no shortcut.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(){
    int input;
    int max = 0;
    while(input != -999){
    printf("Enter a Value : ");
    scanf("%d",&input);
    if(input > max){
        max = input;
        printf("NEW MAX VALUE ENTERED\n");
    }
    printf("Current Max Value: %d\n\n",max);
    }

}

Comment: @AmitKumar: Is there a reason why you copy/pasted that code into a comment? By the way, `input` is uninitialized the first time it's used in the `while` loop test and your code doesn't work if all the values are negative. Go ahead and turn it in as your homework.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Guava's Ints with `min` and `max` methods](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#min(int...)) or [java.util.Collections `min` and `max` methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min(java.util.Collection))

Comment: I knw i can do it in java but i wanna solve this in C language

Comment: You had java tagged at first. Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Really basic example of what you're asking for, this will continue to read in integers until user enters '-999'. Every time the user enters a new max, the program prompts the user.

*READ* if you would like to use this to find the max in an array, just iterate through the array with the same if statement... The example below does not store the user's values...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(){
    int input = 0;
    int max = 0;
    while(input != -999){
    printf("Enter a Value : ");
    scanf(" %d",&input);
    if(input<0)input = 0;
    if(input > max){
        max = input;
        printf("NEW MAX VALUE ENTERED\n");
    }
    printf("Current Max Value: %d\n\n",max);
    }

}
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but what happens if user enters `-1 -2 -3 -999`? And no minimum attempted.

Comment: use of uninitialized variable, not caring for newline/whitespace in `scanf()` AND this question really shouldn't have answers anyways

Comment: Thanks a lot right answer..!!:)

Comment: @FelixPalmen That was my mistake on the errors you brought up, thanks. However, I disagree with you when you said 'AND this question really shouldn't have answers anyways', the whole point of this forum is to help others. We all started somewhere, not everyone understands code the first time they see it, I know this question is 'common sense' to you, but don't put yourself on a pedestal.

Comment: @LearningCODE this site is about programming problems, not "here is my homework, do it for me".

Comment: @FelixPalmen Noticed how I didn't 'do his/her homework', I didn't find the max val in an array, and I didn't attempt to find the minimum, I gave him 'a push in the right direction'.

Comment: @LearningCODE nothing against this answer any more, now that the immediate errors are fixed. But still, this is not the place for this kind of questions, it's just off-topic. (*and* it would help a lot more being forced to research such ridiculously trivial things yourself)

Comment: @LearningCODE just adding now that there *are* kind of "basic" questions that deserve an answer in my opinion, because it's not that easy to find an answer as a "newbie", not exactly knowing what to look for in the first place. Just in my opinion, asking for some really basic *algorithm* doesn't fit that bill. It also fails to achieve another declared goal of this site: collect answers that are valuable for future readers, too. And, in fact, these can help you sometimes, even as a professional software developer.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1183989/2328514) shows one of the SO answers where the max and min are found simultaneously using only 3n/2 comparisons instead of the traditional 2n comparisons(n for min and n for max).