# Difference between same value in array using only one loop javascript

Tags: javascript

How to find the difference between the min and max indexes of the same value in an array with one loop with complexity exactly O(N)?

For example, given array A:

```
[4, 6, 2, 2, 6, 6, 1];
```

the function returns 4.

Comment: You'd probably create a map of values with the first and last index, calculating the difference as you go. You could also update the max index difference as you go too. What have you tried?

Comment: is the requirement only for time? What about space complexity?

Comment: Please check this link I hop you find solution from this link.[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424800/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-the-minimum-or-maximum-value-from-an-array-of-number)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to get the minimum or maximum value from an Array of numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424800/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-the-minimum-or-maximum-value-from-an-array-of-number)

Comment: @HardikChapla—the OP is looking for the biggest distance between equal values, where "distance" is the index of the last occurrence minus the index of the first occurrence of the value.

Comment: Complexity:
· expected worst-case time complexity is O(N);
· expected worst-case space complexity is O(N), beyond input storage (not counting the storage required for input arguments).

Answer (score 1):

I'd use *reduce* to remember the first index of each value, then update the last value and maximum spread as I went along, e.g.

```js
var data = [4, 6, 2, 2, 6, 6, 1];

function getMaxIndexSpread(data) {
  return data.reduce(function(acc, value, index) {

    if (value in acc) {
      acc[value].lastIndex = index

    } else {
      acc[value] = {firstIndex: index, lastIndex: index};
    }
    var spread = acc[value].lastIndex - acc[value].firstIndex;

    if (acc.maxSpread < spread) acc.maxSpread = spread;

    return acc;
  }, {maxSpread: 0}).maxSpread;
}

console.log(getMaxIndexSpread(data));
```

There's likely a funkier way, but this makes sense to me.

```js
var data = [4, 6, 2, 2, 6, 6, 1];

console.log(Math.max(...data.map((v,i) => i - data.indexOf(v))));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   var arr = [4, 6, 2, 2, 6, 6, 1];
    function test(arr) {
        var resultArr = [];
        arr.map(function (v, i, a) {
            for (var j = arr.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                if (v == arr[j]) {
                    resultArr.push({value: v, result: j - i});
//                    console.log(v+'的折扣值'+(j-i));
                    break;
                }
            }
        })
        resultArr.sort(function (a, b) {
            return b.result - a.result;
        })
        console.log(resultArr[0])
    }
    test(arr);
```

Comment: You should explain briefly why this is answering the question.

Comment: How is this O(N)??

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`Array#filter`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi2-6-EkabUAhVKKo8KHa5IC70QFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Ffilter&usg=AFQjCNHgB7IyOa22NG7kCsGZ1ldwMUmkiA&sig2=34aUNDqxJYEs13FX16Ykng) .filter the array without max and min value .Then find max value in filtered array .`...` its [spread syntax](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi-qsaNm6bUAhXCs48KHVLbDJAQFggqMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2FSpread_operator&usg=AFQjCNFHTdMj01YDZlVyslOCL7g9QRz8zA&sig2=V1AKbn7Lk5VP8t7I3YH97w)

```js
var data = [4, 6, 2, 2, 6, 6, 1];

function bet(data) {
  return Math.max(...data.filter(a => a != Math.max(...data) && a != Math.min(...data)))
}

console.log(bet(data))
```

Comment: How is this supposed to work? Given `[4, 6, 2, 2, 6, 6, 1,4]` this still returns 4 when it should return 7. `Math.max(...data)` and `Math.min(...data)` will return the same value every time, so should only be calculated once.

Comment: `[4, 6, 2, 2, 6, 6, 1,4]` how its possible return `7` .returning length of the array or height number value .Can you explain

Comment: As above: "*the OP is looking for the biggest distance between equal values, where "distance" is the index of the last occurrence minus the index of the first occurrence of the value*", so the biggest distance (if a 4 is put at the end) is between the first 4 and the last, so `7– 0 = 7`.